# Read Data Transferred Between USB And OS, C++

Tags: c++, usb, libusb

We have some USB device that send continuously some raw data, And i should logs that data into log files.
So i tried using `libusb` on **GNU/Linux** and **MS-Windows 10** but i recognized when we want to use `libusb` it's well take down the kernel driver and all that data will lost. How i could catch that raw data ?

**NOTE:** *There is no any special device driver in mind, and we looking for a general way to get raw transferred data between USB and OS.*

We use `C++` with `MSVC2017` on **MS-Windows 10** and `GCC 9` on **Debian**.

Comment: What kind of "device" is it? What does it do? What kind of data does it transmit? And can you elaborate on the problems you had with libusb?

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is right here, We need to write a program that capture all kind of device something like Wireshark that i could not understand how Wireshark do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark is capable of [capturing USB](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) data. In my experience, it works better on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, Wireshark it's using `USBPcap` and it's have not any API documents. And i could not understand how Wireshark uses it.

Comment: Do you want to capture the data programmatically while keeping the kernel driver running? With Wireshark, you can easily view and analyze the captured data.

Comment: Yes i what that, I know Wireshark can do it for me But i should write the program to do it for me. i see Wireshark source code and read the [Caturing USB](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) for that but i could not find any documents for using `USBPcap` APIs.